# Find a string in a text file, and then print the first words of the following lines in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find a keyword in a text file. And then, print the first 3 words of the 3 following lines.

here is an exemple of my text file:

```
...
NAME SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON ...
ABCD BH YZ     A 1236 53.70
EFGH BH XH     A 1243 56.80 
IJKL SZ TU     B 1248 32.30
MNOP SZ RT       1252 18.50
QRST BH DF     B 1253 54.40
```

So, i would like to find the string : "NAME", and then print the following "ABCD", EFGH" and "IJKL".

Here is my code in Python :

```
sfile=open("file.txt")

while True:

  line = sfile.readline()

  if line.startswith('NAME'):       
    item1 = sfile.readline()[0:4]
    item2 = sfile.readline()[0:4]
    item3 = sfile.readline()[0:4]
    break


sfile.close()
```

But it doesn't work ...

Any help with this would be appreciated! Thks :)

Comment: do you need python for that? `grep '^NAME' yourfile --after-context=3`

Comment: I believe you are looking for the `print` keyword.

Comment: Well, I am doing my all program in Python ! and of course, I use the print keyword, but after closing my file.

Comment: How large can these text files get?

Comment: The maximum size is about 40 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I have solved my problem !

here is my solution :

```
  sfile=open("file.txt")
  data_sfile=sfile.read()
  myArray = data_sfile.split('\n') 

  for i in range(len(myArray)):
        if myArray[i].find("NAME ")>=0:
          item1 = myArray[i+1]
          item2 = myArray[i+2]
          item3 = myArray[i+3]
          break

      item1 = item1 [0:5] 
      item2 = item2 [0:5] 
      item2 = item2 [0:5]

  sfile.close()
```

Okay, it is not the prettiest solution, but it works !

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The first step you need to take is to convert the Text file to a suitable data structure, I chose Dictionary for this problem, you may use nested lists as well.

Secondly I converted the name of various columns as keys of this Dictionary and then assigned the row values under those columns as the values of that keys.

```
dictionary = {}
with open("sample.txt") as sfile:
    data = sfile.readlines()
    keys = data[0].split()
    for k in keys:
        #For creating an empty dictionary
        dictionary[k] = []
    for values in data[1:]:
        for i,value in enumerate(values.strip().split()):
            dictionary[keys[i]].append(value)
    #print dictionary #To review the data structure.

keyword = "NAME"#raw_input("Please enter the keyword:")
print dictionary[keyword][:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, not sure if it's what you're looking for.

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as sfile:

  lines = sfile.read()
  rows = lines.split('\n')

  for columns in rows:
    items = columns.split(' ')
    print items[0]
```

Comment: It is a good idea ! Now if i want to create an array, in this way it will be easier to find the words I am looking for !